# What is the subjunctive root of “être”?

Tags: verbes, conjugaison, subjonctif

Normally, to find the root of a verb in the subjunctive tense, you would take the *nous*-form and remove the *-ons*. In *être*, the *nous*-form is *nous sommes*, so there is no *-ons* to remove. What is the subjunctive root of *être*?

Comment: http://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/%EAtre.html

Comment: It's irregular in the subjunctive. Many verbs are. I suggest learning them all. You can find them all conjugated on conjugation and dictionary sites; there's no need to ask for conjugations here.

Comment: Every frequent verb is irregular (être, avoir, aller, faire, pouvoir, dire,...). It is a universal invariant in all languages. Hopefully, you ear them often so you learn them fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Être, présent du subjonctif :

> que je sois
>   que tu sois
>   qu'il/qu'elle/qu'on soit
>   que nous soyons
>   que vous soyez
>   qu'ils/qu'elles soient

You would say the root would be "soi-"

"être" is as strange in French as it is in English : I *am*, you *are*, he *is*, don't show any roots either.